# Installation of encryption key in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, rsa, aspnet-regiis.exe

For development purposes, I need to install an RSA key into my local machine.

The guide says:

> Install the RSA key by running following command from the prompt on
>      your machine: 
>      c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727>aspnet_regiis -pi
>      tuexampleKeys C:\tu-key.xml

Only problem is, aspnet_regiis has been discontinued. It doesn't seem to exist on windows 10. And I could not google any replacements other thant dism for installing the dotnet framework.

I also tried installing dotnet 4 to get it that way. But it says its already installed.

So, what is an old man todo ? :)

Comment: "aspnet_regiis has been discontinued" - what? I just went into c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework and I can find versions of it under both the v2.0.50727 and v4.0.30319 directories (Windows 10)

Comment: You're absolultely correct. I can't even read anymore :)